# UIButton stops working?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm having a weird issue, I know it's a bit futile if I don't paste the code here, but I think it would be overkill.

What would cause a UIButton to stop working, ie :

- its IBAction doesn't respond anymore
- the highlighted state doesn't respond anymore

This button belongs to a Scrollview that I'm moving up after this particular button is pressed, problem is : it only doesn't it does it once, then doesn't respond anymore ..

Any classic example of that ?

Answer (score 0):

This tends to be a memory release issue. Make sure you are not releasing a variable that doesn't need to be.

Comment: Yeah, thought it could be something related, but I`ve commented out all my releases , still happening :( grrr